# How to access cross domain site (SharePoint) using .ajax call using AD user credentials

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I need to query SharePoint List from simple javascript, using .ajax call. I need to use a AD user credentials who will have read permissions to the SharePoint Site.
I am doing something like this but getting a lots of errors. Any suggestions.

```
function getBookingDetails(siteURL, listName, podName, currentTime) 
{ 
var filterQuery = "?$filter=(EventDate le datetime'"+ currentTime +"') and (EndDate ge datetime'"+ currentTime +"') and (PodType/PodType eq '"+ podName +"')";

    var user = "****@AD2012.***";
    var passwordtemp = "**********";

    $.ajax({
        url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+ listName +"')/items" + filterQuery,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(user, passwordtemp));
        },
        success: function (data) {
             // Doing something with data ..            
            }},
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
} // function ends ..
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205514/get-access-token-for-update-list-item-using-rest-api-and-javascript-application

Comment: Looks like that only works for SP with Office 365.  Not sure of OP's version though.